# Posting relationship status to newsfeed

Tags: facebook

I recently changed my relationship status to "Separated" unlike other statuses, this one does not automatically publish to my newsfeed. Is there a way for me to publish this change?

Answer (score 2):

This indicates that you have set this to not publish. You will need edit your privacy settings and allow Facebook to share this information.

- Go to https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy
- Click `Customize settings`
- Select the drop down next to `Relationships` and choose who you want to share this information with.

I would imagine that if you want to publish your Relationship status change then you will have to set it back before changing your privacy settings.

Once you have amended your privacy settings then update your Relationship Status to "separated" and it should publish this to your wall.

**EDIT**

How you control who can see your Relationship Status has now been moved.

- You need to click on your profile to view your timeline.
- Click `About`
- Under the section `Basic Info` click `Edit`
- In the section named `Relationship Status` to the far right of the box is a small drop down that lists who this information is visible to.

[image: Facebook - relationship status settings]

Comment: Note that, as of January 2012, this no longer works. There's no "Customize Settings" link on that page, and no place to change the Relationship Status changes that I could find.

Comment: @CraigWalker Updated my answer :)

Comment: Barry: That's useful information... unfortunately, it doesn't really help with trying to get the relationship status change onto the wall/feed, which is what @Foster and I are trying to do.

Comment: @CraigWalker have you updated your relationship status *after* you have amended you're privacy settings? Also, it is worth mentioning that if you adding someone to your relationship status you will need to wait for them to approve the changes before it posted on your wall.

Comment: Yup, I did. It was already set to "friends", which is exactly how I wanted it. I set it to "Separated", and saw no wall update. Then I changed it to "Single", and saw the post to my wall. When I changed it back to "Separated", Facebook actually *removed* the previous "Single" wall post. None of these require confirmation. It appears that Separated and/or Single is a special case when it comes to wall updates.